# Can I use Magento without mcrypt?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, password, encryption-key, mcrypt

My shop was moved to a server without mcrypt and for some reason mcrypt can not be installed (don't ask me why!).

Looks like passwords are only encrypted with md5 with a salt (bad!) so I wonder what mcrypt is used for at all. Someone hacked Magento and was able to [install it without mcrypt](http://www.davidheidel.net/installing-magento-without-mcrypt/). Does not sound good to me but it was working for him.

Now i would like to know what for encrypt is used and will the show break if I replace it with a dummy? Is there a better workaround? May get secure random from openssl and add an encryption lib?

**TL;DR**

- What is mcrypt used for in Magento?
- Is a good workaround possible?

Comment: I was not asking if it's needed. I know it is. Question is what it's needed for and if a good workaround is possible.

Comment: what you mean workaround? there is no workarounds for minimum requirements to run the application... lol

Comment: this question is the same as: my hosting without pdo, innodb, ... etc

Comment: @MagenX Well, mcrypt is not used for password, so the question is what is it used for and do I need that feature? Also there are [other](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) [crypt](http://www.gilfether.com/phpcrypt/) libs that provide the used functions just a bit slower. In theory you can replace mcrypt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*MCrypt* is not used for password and URL key hashing but for encrypting and decrypting sensitive data such as API passwords, e.g. stored in / retrieved from the system configuration.

All *MCrypt* functionality is encapsulated in [`Varien_Crypt_Mcrypt`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.7.0.2/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php). This class again is accessed via [`Mage_Core_Model_Encryption`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php). The encryption model that should be used throughout the application is configured in the [`config/global/helpers/core/encryption_model`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml#L98) node.

So (in theory) there is sort of a chance to replace this one by your own encryption model – as long as it satisfies the former's interface. At first glance it looks like you need to extend `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption` and replace the [`_getCrypt`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php#L108) method. This should return a class instance that implements the same methods as `Varien_Crypt_Mcrypt` – but makes use of a different encryption library.

Answer (score 1):

You could patch the Magento code (for example via the `app/local` codepool) and replace the mcrypt functionality by those from PHPSecLib which offer an implementation of the functionality in pure PHP http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How to install php_mcrypt in wamp? @Alex